# how to compare data between dates on multiply items at the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inventory

I have a table of items that I track inventory on daily basis (mysql)

```
| item_id | qty    | created_at |
| ------- | -------| ---------- |
| 1       | 5     | 2021-04-08 |
| 1       | 30     | 2021-04-07 |
| 1       | 100    | 2021-04-06 |
| 2       | 100    | 2021-04-08 |
| 2       | 0      | 2021-04-07 |
| 2       | 0      | 2021-04-06 |
| 3       | 0      | 2021-04-08 |
| 3       | 50     | 2021-04-07 |
| 3       | 100    | 2021-04-06 |
```

I wonder how can I write an SQL query that analyze all items in the table and response some insights

for ex.
item_id = 1 ---> item is almost out of stock (5% limit point)

item_id = 2 ---> item just returned to stock (was 0 yesterday new we have 100)

item_id = 3 ---> item is out of stock today

also if there is another ideas for monitor the stock insights I'll be happy to know..

Thanks for all the helpers.

Comment: Assuming nobody buys item 2 today, what will your 'insight' display tomorrow?

Comment: Anyway, it sounds like you want to explore conditional statements - i.e. CASE... WHEN

Comment: 'for ex. item_id = 1 ---> item is almost out of stock (5% limit point)' - I don't get this where does the 5% rule come from

Comment: *item is almost out of stock (5% limit point)* What specifies this "limit"? No such data in shown table.

Comment: 5% is just a decision that effect all items, I want to know if my item stock is close to end so I alert to place an order..

Comment: just to make it more clear this table track my supplier stock not my stock... so I want to create an automation that notify me when the supplier back to stock or stock is about to end...

Answer (score 1):

Consider running SQL jobs on regular time schedule.

***Item is almost out of stock (5% limit)***

Well five percent of what total (I assume it's not always 100 pcs). Create table with item_id and threshold value. If current stock is lower or equal to threshold value report it.

***Item just returned to stock.***

> currentDay

is a function to return actual date like '2021/04/08' I am not familiar with mySql function/syntax

```
select item_id from myTable where qty > 0 and created_at = currentDay 
   and item_id IN (select item_id from myTable where qty = 0 and created_at = currentDay-1
```

***Item is out of stock today***

```
select item_id from myTable where qty = 0 and created_at = currentDay
```

//Edit after comments

1st comment: ***In case you want to see item that today is out of stock and yesterday it was not***, tweak the provided query. Switch qty in conditions.

```
select item_id from myTable where qty = 0 and created_at = currentDay 
   and item_id IN (select item_id from myTable where qty > 0 and created_at = currentDay-1
```

2nd comment: Consider this. If your initial stock is 2pcs at day D, stock increase by 1000 at D+1 and stock increase by 70 at D+2. In case you take your stock qty from day D, your 5% is 0.1 pcs.

First of all that won't happen, so you should round up to nearest whole number (qty = 1) and second the stock qty warning may not be relevant. When your total stock is 1072 pcs your warning will trigger when qty <= 1 since it's based on stock qty from first day.

Comment: select item_id from myTable where qty = 0 and created_at = currentDay
this query return all the items that not in stock... I want to get all the items that was in stock yesturday but out of stock today...

Comment: about the 5% it should show me all the items that remain 5% of the first day I started to track the stock (for ex. item_id = 1 , first row (2021-04-06) is 100 pcs so when qty hits 5 it show me)

Comment: Ok that was not the originial question, so I added the solution. And the percentage task... read what others wrote and think about it. I believe you are setting yourself a trap with current idea of 5% computation.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `lag()` and some conditional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when qty <= 5
             then 'Almost out of stock'
             when qty > 0 and lag(qty) over (partition by item_id order by created_at) = 0
             then 'Just returned to stock'
             when qty = 0 and lag(qty) over (partition by item_id order by created_at) > 0
             then 'Out of stock today'
             when qty = 0
             then 'Still out of stock.  How long will this go on?'
             else 'Okay'
        end) as status
from t
```